# Airties 2610 Wifi USB Adapter Not Working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, usb

I am new to Linux and Ubuntu. I have the ver 20.1 Ubuntu installed. Got almost everything working except the Wifi connection. I have Airties 2610 USB as adapter. There is no linux driver on the homepage of Airties. lsusb command shows Airties in terminal -->

```
root@OzgurUbuntu:/home/ozgur/rtl88x2bu# 

lsusb
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1eda:2610 AirTies Wireless Networks AirTies Wireless Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I've also tried the Windows driver with ndiswan but didn't work.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: There is no such version of Ubuntu as 20.1 There is a 20.10 You can never use a windows driver in Ubuntu.

Comment: Ok , sorry, i forgot the zero. The version is 20.10.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?probe=0368e2fa40 where it sats: "Driver is not found or not configured. We have not found a driver for the device in any Linux kernel versions up to 5.11 (according to the LKDDb) or known additional packages."